# Calling Environment.Exit in a windows service

Tags: c#, service, exit

Does calling Environment.Exit from within a Windows service make the SCM call the onStop() method of the service, or is this behaviour unpredictable ?

I have a couple of Windows services that have this code. Unfortunately, I cant remove this behaviour. But I need to know whether onStop() will be called to decide whether to put some common stopping code in that method or within the method that calls Environment.Exit.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can a service written in .NET self-terminate?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/554276/can-a-service-written-in-net-self-terminate)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`Enviroment.Exit` will close the process which is wrapped by the service.

Therefore, calling it, will not call `onStop()` method.

You can invoke the method by yourself instead of calling to `Exit`

You can use the following code to invoke `SCM stop`

```
System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController svc = new System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController("NameOfYourService");
svc.Stop();
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer !!
So this behaviour is to be expected always right ?

Comment: This is what you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/a/554292/1361084
Its Jon Skeets answer to the comment @CodeCaster posted.

Comment: Hi @Ofiris i just come across this thread. just wonder can we stop winservice from any routine of win service itself using ServiceController class ? or do i need separate apps which can stop my service ? please guide. thanks

Comment: If I understood right, yes, you can call the `Stop` method of the `ServiceController` class.
See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/554276/can-a-service-written-in-net-self-terminate