# Best Practices for dealing with dead worker threads in a .net Windows Service?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, windows-services

I've written a small Windows Service that performs a task at a regular interval.  It seems to be working fine, but I have a concern.

The `OnStart` method starts a "worker thread" that takes on the responsibility of performing  the task, waiting for an interval to elapse, and repeating the task.

In the "Windows Services" section of "Administrative Tools", I can set it so that the service restarts automatically if it fails.

However, in the case that the worker thread throws exception, the service appears to continue running.  I think that if the worker thread throws exception, the service should be considered stopped, and Windows should take the exception specified in the service settings.

What are the best practices for accomplishing this?

Comment: Supposing that I want the service to stop when the worker thread dies, how can I do that?

Comment: Related: [Can a service written in .NET self-terminate?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/554276/945456)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In our case, we don't want a single task to crash the service (since maybe it was just bad data and all the other tasks will complete fine), so we just wrap all the worker logic in a `try/catch` and log any exception we hit. I do have some exception tracking code that will shut the service down if it's consistently failing though (e.g. network or database is down).

However, if your service only does a single task and it failing is good cause to stop *everything*, then I believe writing code to marshal the exception back to the main thread would work. You could save off [SynchronizationContext.Current](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.synchronizationcontext.current%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) when you start the service, and use it to get back to the main thread when you encounter an exception. I believe that's stop (ehem, crash) the service. Pardon the code if it's not quite right. I don't have VS in front of me at the moment.

```
void OnStart()
{
  _mainThread = SynchronizationContext.Current();
}

void DoWork()
{
  try
  {
    // Do the stuff...
  }
  catch (Exception e)
  {
    _mainThread.Post(() => Throw);
  }
}
```

**Edit:**

On second thought, I think you could accomplish what you want like this... simple :)

*(Editted with suggestion in comment from Ishmaeel to use `Environment.Exit` instead of `Stop`)*

```
void DoWork()
{
  try
  {
    // Do the stuff...
  }
  catch (Exception e)
  {
    LogException(e);
    Environment.Exit(1);
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't have a lot of experience with multithreading.  Can you explain how the SynchronizationContext works in this context?  Also, I thought that the main thread exits after the worker thread is started, or am I mistaken?

Comment: I haven't fully grokked it so I'm afraid I can't fully explain it to you, and I'm unsure about the threads as well. I'm kind of taking knowledge from the UI world and apply it to services. See edit for another (much simpler) idea.

Comment: _RE: Second thought:_ Actually, calling `Stop` from within the service itself is **not a good idea**. That method is meant to be called by Windows' service manager. The service will not really stop, it will encounter additional `ThreadAbortException`s and go into that phantom state that Daniel was trying to avoid. Forcing an abnormal crash that will make it possible to take advantage of service recovery options requires `Environment.Exit`.

Comment: Thanks @Ishmaeel, editted with your suggestion. Found a similar recommendation here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3255244/945456