# Check for file existence OnStart() and then stop service

Tags: c#

I have a small problem :)

I just want to start a service, after the start(or during the start) to check if a file exists.

If doesn't, then to stop the service...
Here is the code:

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {

        if (!System.IO.File.Exists(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName + ".config"))
        {
            EventLog m_EventLog = new EventLog("");
            m_EventLog.Source = "X";
            m_EventLog.WriteEntry("TEXT HERE", EventLogEntryType.Warning);
            base.OnStop();
        }
        else
        {
        //SOME OTHER FUNCTIONS
        }
    }
    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        //CODE HERE; (Or Nothing...)
    }
```

I know that this is a little not correct, but i really can't find the best solution for me for this case...
Help :(

Comment: Am I missing something, this looks fine to me...

Comment: Is your code not working or are you asking for a Code Review?

Comment: the base.OnStop(); is not working, i mean the service is not stopping;
So i need to stop the service if the file not exists(config file).

Comment: `OnStop()` is called when the service is stopping. To actually stop it, call `Stop()`. See [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/554276/can-a-service-written-in-net-self-terminate).

Comment: In that case have you tried using `base.Stop()`? using only `onStop` won't do much

Comment: I know about Stop() or ServiceBase.Stop(), but this also not working...

Comment: Where you are calling `base.OnStop();` call instead `base.Stop();`, this will automatically run the `OnStop()` method

Comment: On start of the Service, if i call Stop() i get a error: The service "ServiceName" on "LocalComputer" was started and after that stopped. Some services automaticly are stopping, if they are not used by other applications(i translated this from russian, so...)

Comment: That message is exactly what you should expect the Service Manager to show you when you start a service that stops itself from its startup method. It shows an administrator that something is wrong with the service, and that they should investigate, which fits your scenario exactly.

Comment: Ok, that's good, i have now this message, can i do something to stop the service without this message?

Comment: Guys, can anybody help me?
If i call the Stop() method in the OnStart(), i have a message..."The service "ServiceName" on "LocalComputer" was started and after that stopped. Some services automaticly are stopping, if they are not used by other applications(i translated this from russian, so...) "

Can i do this thing without this message at the end?

Comment: Your question has been put on hold as duplicate, because what you asked has already been asked in another question. If you then have a new question, read [ask] and post a new question. Be sure to share your research and be very explicit in what you want to happen.

Comment: Sorry CodeCaster, but in that case, there is no answer for my question...
You also gave me an answer, to call Stop(), but if i call stop i have a message that the service starts and stops...but i don't need that message, that's the problem. I just don't want to open other case how to handle this message(if this is possible), i am shure that you have a good answer, but i don't know why you don't want to answer me :)